# How can I git-bisect when I compile with Visual Studio?

Tags: git, testing, visual-studio-2019, git-bisect

I'd like to git-bisect a somewhat large project (20 min compilation time). I've written a test that identifies the bug. If I compiled using make and make test, I'd simply git-bisect the old-fashioned way and checking if the test succeeds or fails.

How can I use git-bisect when the project is loaded into Visual Studio? Is there some file caching/reloading that I have to worry about, or can I simply keep git-bisect in an open shell and Visual Studio 2019 in another?

Comment: I think you can. Normally VS detect the changes (it's been a long time since VS plays well with git) and building is enough. If you're not confident enough and you have the time, **rebuild all** every times before running the test.